# Comparing a parent and a child node for similarity

Tags: javascript, dom, comparison, nodes

Given the following structure

```
<p>
  <p>
    <span>
      <span class="a">
        <p>
```

I want to turn it into

```
<p>
  <span>
    <span class="a">
```

Yes, the first block is invalid, we'll ignore that. It's just an example.

Basically, what I want to do is check if any child is necessary, and if not, remove it, keeping all of its children. So, all `<p>`'s are identical, straight elements, therefore only the top one is really doing anything (in my code, I realize that's not always the case). However, the spans, though identical in name, are not the same, as one has `class="a"` and the other has no class, thus they both stay.

The expansion of what I'm looking for would not just work if class name differs, but any of the properties that might make it actually different.

I was thinking that I could use `node1.attributes === node2.attributes`, but that doesn't work, even though `node1` and `node2` attributes have a length of zero. Furthermore, `node1 === node2`, `node1.isEqualNode(node2)`, and `node1.isSameNode(node2)` all fail as well. And rightly so, as they're not the same node.

So how can I rightly check to see if the node is eligible for removal?

Another example, of when this would actually be useful

```
<p>
  <b>
    Some text
    <u>that is
      <b>bolded</b> <!-- << That <b> is totally useless, and should be removed. -->
    </u>
  </b>
</p>
```

No Jquery please.

Comment: You will first need to clearly define what a "necessary" child node is.

Comment: That's what the examples are for. Elements which are the same as a parent, and which seemingly add nothing to the markup. As noted in the original post, external CSS may technically be able to change that, but we're ignoring that, as that exception is irrelevant to my case. Technically it should work for a `<ul>` inside of a `<ul>`, though I'll be putting an exception in for things like that. However, if one ul has a `class`, `id`, `onclick`, `width`, or any of the other numerous attributes available, it should not match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up with:

```
it = doc.createNodeIterator(doc.firstChild, NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL, null, false);
node = it.nextNode();
while(node){                
    // Remove any identical children        
    // Get the node we can move around. We need to go to the parent first, or everything will be true
    var tempNode = node.parentNode;
    // While we haven't hit the top - This checks for identical children
    while(tempNode && tempNode !== div && tempNode !== doc){
        // If they're the same name, which isn't not on the noDel list, and they have the same number of attributes
        if(node.nodeName === tempNode.nodeName && noDel.indexOf(node.nodeName) < 0 && node.attributes.length === tempNode.attributes.length){
            // Set flag that is used to determine if we want to remove or not
            var remove = true;

            // Loop through all the attributes
            for(var i = 0; i < node.attributes.length; ++i){
                // If we find a mismatch, make the flag false and leave
                if(node.attributes[i] !== tempNode.attributes[i]){
                    remove = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // If we want to remove it
            if(remove){
                // Create a new fragment
                var frag = doc.createDocumentFragment();

                // Place all of nodes children into the fragment
                while(node.firstChild){
                    frag.appendChild(node.firstChild);
                }

                // Replace the node with the fragment
                node.parentNode.replaceChild(frag, node);
            }
        }
        // Otherwise, look at the next parent
        tempNode = tempNode.parentNode;
    }

    // Next node
    node = it.nextNode();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Oh this would be an interesting interview question! 
Regarding the solution- make a function to traverse the DOM any which way you like, which receives a predicate  function as an argument. Then collect an array of items which pass the predicate, and do your 'fixing' afterwards. 
In your case, the predicate is obviously some isChildNecessary function, which you will need to implement.

How would you plan on handling a second pass, and a third, etc? When do you stop? After removing some nodes, you may end up having another 'invalid' state.. Just something to think about.

Comment: Happy to give interview questions, however, this is not an interview, and your response might as well be an interview question, which is not an answer.

Comment: I cant believe you downvoted this. I will not write an implementation for you, i helped you along the way. Good luck getting people to help you with with that attitude.

Comment: You didn't even help me move along. All you said was to write a function to traverse the DOM, and compare the elements. Considering I'm asking how to compare the elements, and you told me to compare the elements, how does this even help? I know what I need to do, it's the implementation / comparison that I'm asking for help with in the first place.

Comment: do a for each loop on the attributes in a, compare with b, and vice versa. But this all depends on how you want to compare them- your description is vague and this in itself may not suffice.